# What can be used with [UIDevice currentDevice]?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uniqueidentifier, ipod

What can be with `[UIDevice currentDevice]`, such as uniqueIdentifier? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the properties and methods associated with a UIDevice Object are described in the [UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

To access the Unique Identifer, you can do something like:

```
NSString *identifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Comment: Just to note, in iOS5, the uniqueIdentifier property will be deprecated. Here is a TechCrunch article explaining more: http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/19/apple-ios-5-phasing-out-udid/

Comment: @Suhail Patel, How is it supposed to id a user in iOS 5 without UDID? It's there any best practice thing?

Answer (score 5):

Because this is slightly out of date now I am just giving an up to date answer.

Because `Apple` has seen fit to stop developers using the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];` from `iOS 6` onwards which `Suhail Patels` answer advices to use. They have now started telling developers to use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];`, but some developers are confused on whether they are still allowed to use `uniqueIdentifier` even if they are still developing for `iOS 5` and below or not. `Apple` have been a bit fussy about this just saying :

```
"Apps that use the `UDID` will be rejected in the App Store review process.."
```

Come on `Apple` give us a bit more detail.

Anyway because of the confusion behind this some developers have started using [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID) to get a unique identifier. Here is some code on how it can be used:

```
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
        // Use: [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    } else {
        // Use: [OpenUDID value];
    }
```

**EDIT**

Some developers have also now seen fit to start using the MAC Address since `UDID` has been deprecated. This is because the MAC addresses are hardware based and therefore can't be changed. For those of you that which to go for the MAC Address way apple have provided some sample code on [Getting MAC Address](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Listings/GetPrimaryMACAddress_GetPrimaryMACAddress_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000698-GetPrimaryMACAddress_GetPrimaryMACAddress_c-DontLinkElementID_3).

Comment: @downvoter please leave reason for downvote, don't just downvote. If you leave a reason I can correct my mistake, improve an answer or just work on the reason. So leaving a reason would benefit everyone.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 5, you can create a new, but not unique identifier with this:

```
CFUUIDRef UIID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef UIIDString = (CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, UIID));
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",UIIDString];
```

Save it in a file and use it like unique identifier

Comment: For iOS 6 and later you can use [[UIDevice currentdevice] identifierForVendor];