# Apple's Mobile Device Management without UDID

Tags: ios, mdm

After installing the MDM profile, when a device registers with the server
for MDM; the server gets the following response(s) from device:

**Authenticate**:

```
{'Topic': 'com.apple.mgmt.External.dadd0670-xxx', 'UDID'
: 'xxxx', 'MessageType': 'Authenticate'}
```

**TokenUpdate**:

```
{'Topic': 'com.apple.mgmt.External.dadd0670-xxx', 'UDID' : 'xxx', 'Token': xxxx, 'PushMagic': 'xxxx', 'MessageType': 'TokenUpdate'}
```

As you can see in the response, to map that `MDM` token(we get it in TokenUpdate command) with a device we can use only the device's `UDID`.

So, in the iOS app I have to send the device's UDID to our server to link that
token with the device. I am using `"[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]"` to do this.

But, now apple is not accepting apps that access uniqueIdentifier.

[Protocol Reference](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf)

Comment: so you want a replacement to this 
`[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` ?

Comment: You can use `[UIDevice uniqueDeviceIdentifier];` as the replacement

Comment: Have a  look at my answer on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128828/what-can-be-used-with-uidevice-currentdevice/16099440#16099440

Comment: Have you solved this yet? Im into the same problem as well. Was thinking of sending the UDID via a push notification to my iOS app

Answer (score 2):

Starting in iOS 6.0+, Apple has provided new identifiers that you can use. Your options are:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]]
```

This is meant for identifying a device to a specific vendor. Hence, it will be the same for the same developer's apps, but it will vary across different developers' apps. [See the docs here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

Alternatively, you can use:

```
[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier]
```

This returns a value that is the same across all vendors. However, it is meant for advertising purposes only (and in some instances, can be changed... such as if the device is erased). [See the docs here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingIdentifier)

You might also refer to the docs on `uniqueIdentifier` which can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) and have commentary about the above two replacement options (and also another option that uses `UUID` of the `NSUUID` class).

The main limitation of the above two mentioned options is that they are available for iOS 6.0+ only... if you must target iOS 5.0+, you also have another option which is creating your own identifier (such as based on the MAC address which is done by [UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) for example).

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses are unique, every iPhone device will have it. Use macaddress to create a unique string just like UDID and use it instead.

Here is a [github link to UIDevice category](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5/blob/master/Classes/UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.m) which does the job. Hope it helps!

Amar.

Answer (score 0):

MAC Address are not available in iOS7

It will constantly returning 02:00:00:00:00:00

Apple has stated

> MAC addresses in iOS 7
>   August 22, 2013 If your apps use the MAC address to identify an iOS
>   device, the system will return the same static value for all devices
>   running iOS 7. Please update your apps to use the identifierForVendor
>   property of UIDevice. If you need an identifier for advertising
>   purposes, use the advertisingIdentifier property of ASIdentifierManager.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8222013a

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this is to use the new Managed Apps functionality and have your MDM deliver the UDID down to the device via the configuration PList.

Below is a link to a sample project which pulls configuration settings from a PList delivered by the MDM. In your case you would just have your MDM send down the UDID.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html

I recognize this is not the best solution in the world but it is one way of mapping an app on a device to a device record in MDM.